# Winning strategy in game

Tags: mathematics, game, game-theory

Context: I played this game at one point (and lost) and now I'm wondering whether it was possible to win or not.
We have a hexagonal board like this:
[image]
I'm defining the following terms:

1. Each hexagon is called a piece.
2. A wall is a border of the board. There are four walls- left, right, top and bottom. 
   The entire top border is a wall, i.e. the border shaped /¯\_/¯\_/¯\ is the top wall. 
   Similarly for the other walls.

The rules are as follows:

1. Player A starts from the piece marked A, and Player B starts from the piece marked B.
2. In a turn, a player can "claim" any one piece for himself and colour it (blue for A, pink for B).
3. A piece once claimed cannot be claimed by the opposing player.
4. To win, a player must create a continuous sequence of pieces from his starting hexagon to a non-adjacent wall (thus A must create a continuous sequence to the bottom or right wall, and B to the top or left wall).

If player A starts the game, can B have a winning strategy? Please explain in detail.

Comment: Do consider posting a new question asking, who will win if both players play optimally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If player A starts then player B

> cannot

have a winning strategy because

> if they did, then player A could follow the same strategy and win sooner. That is: player A could pick a cell, *pretend* that player B has claimed it as B's first move, and then follow that winning strategy rotated through 180 degrees. If at some point B actually *does* pick the cell A pretended they started with, A should pick another yet-unclaimed cell and pretend B claimed that one. If B's winning strategy worked, then A would end up winning in this way -- which means that B can't have had a winning strategy after all.

Comment: The classic [strategy-stealing argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy-stealing_argument)!

Comment: Oh, man! I need to contact the maths teacher that made us play this game :)

Comment: But is there a winning strategy for A?

Comment: _That_ question wasn't asked :-). Often the answer is "yes, because if there's no B-path from B's starting place to another side then necessarily there is an A-path from A's starting place to another side". But I don't think that's true here, because you can draw parallel (SW-to-NE-ish) lines of A-cells and B-cells that block both A's and B's starting place from the non-adjacent sides. A might still have a win, but it's not so obvious.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan But can we say that if both players play to the best of their ability, then A will always win?

Comment: @Righter Comment because I haven't checked all the lines, but if pieces are labelled like a chessboard (so A is on A5, B is on E1), as far as I can tell, B4 wins. It threatens D4, so B must play in C5,C4,D4,E5,or E4. If C4, then B3 threatens A2 and C2, so B must play B2, but then A wins with C3. If B plays anything else, A plays B2 and I think is just too fast.

Comment: Actually, 1. ... E4 2. B2 C2 might defend. Against 1. ... E4, I think 2. C3 might win. Still haven't checked all lines.

Comment: @alphacapture 1 b4 e4 2. b2 c2 and now 3. b1 b3 4.c4 c3 5.d3 e3 6. d2 and wins on d1 or e2 from move 3 all pink moves were forced.